# Symfony2 - customizing FormType classes

Tags: php, forms, symfony, formbuilder

I have few cases where I need to ugly customizing of my FormType classes.

First one is that I need to check if the `state` of `user` is active in this case disable possibility to edit `username`. But just adding `disabled` atribute is not protecting input to be not submitted. So I decided not to show username input field. I achieved it by passing boolean through options.

Controller:

```
$userForm = $this->createForm(UserType::class, $user, array(
    'is_active' => ($user->getState() == 'active')
));
```

And then in UserType class:

```
if ($options['is_active']) {
    $builder
        ->add('username', EmailType::class);
}

$builder
    ->add('firstName', TextType::class),
...
```

Second case is that I need to remove `NotBlank()` constraint and add `'required' => false` attribute from `FileType` field when profile photo is uploaded. I achieved it in similar way by passing boolean through options.

Controller:

```
$userForm = $this->createForm(UserType::class, $user, array(
    'is_uploaded' => !empty($photo)
));
```

UserType class:

```
// achieved same way as previous problem
```

My questions would be:

- What recommendations would be dealing with these kind of cases?
- Is what I did correct and acceptable?
- Is there a documentation or examples dealing with any of these cases?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can move all this form configuration's logic into the form class.

Since you pass `$user` entity into the form with:

```
$userForm = $this->createForm(UserType::class, $user, array( // <- $user is passed
    'is_uploaded' => !empty($photo)
));
```

You can access it in `builForm` method with:

```
    $user = $builder->getData();
```

Then you can verify all the condifions inside the form and there's no need for making mess in controller.

Comment: Are you sure about $builder->getData().  As far as I can tell the only way to get the forms data during the build process is to use a form event which involves making a listener and what not.

Comment: Please notice that it's called on **builder**, not **form**. It's not the same `getData` that you have on your mind. This is initial data that you pass as 2nd param to `createForm` method or via `data` item in options array (3rd param).

Comment: That looks sweet. So your answer is that I can customize form logic inside? And this version you suggested is recommended? Please clarify answer and I will assign as correct one :)

Comment: Yes, it makes your form reusable and cosistent with the entity. Please also note that this *logic* is not a *business rule*, but the way you *build the form*, so it perfectly fits to be encapsulated inside the form class.